# How can I notice the first launch of App to determine a property value working with UserDefaults?

Tags: swift

I have this simple function like this:

```
func myFunction() {
    
    let showHelpViewInStartUp: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "showHelpViewInStartUp")
    
    if showHelpViewInStartUp {
        // show help view
    }
    
}
```

The goal of this function is to show help view in startup if user checked the option, and not showing the help view if the user unchecked the option. The issue is here that I want the help view get showed in first Launch of app 100%, for that reason showHelpViewInStartUp would be false in first Launch! and that is the issue. I have issue about the standard approach for such things, no issue about writing or reading UserDefaults.

Comment: One way to go could be to store an integer instead, 0 (or nothing) stored means first time, 1 is show view and 2 is do not show view. Basically like using an enum instead of a bool when there are more than 2 states involved

Comment: In the fact I landed to use `UserDefaults.standard.string` nil means first time, "NO" means not first time.

Comment: Well if you want two values instead of one that is your choice

Comment: But I think your way is better, because I could use your way and adding one unit at each launch for later use cases like asking for Rating or something like that.